# Is there any corpus for idioms?

Tags: english, corpora, idiomaticity

I'm looking for a corpus for English (American, GB, Australian) idioms. Preferably created manually, because I already have two, but they are rather small and were built semi-automatically.

Comment: One example - TroFi Example Base http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~anoop/students/jbirke/

Comment: Another one - SAID (A Syntactically Annotated Idiom Database), by Kuiper, McCann, Quinn, Aitchison, and van der Veer 2003.